# I'm curious about what ldc short for in JVM?

Tags: jvm, bytecode

> ByteCode：ldc pushes a one-word constant onto the operand stack.
>   ldc takes a single parameter, , which is the value to push.

Most of the bytecodes in JVM can figure out their name by the code description. However, the ldc, I don't see any clue.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ldc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose it is LoaD Constant but I do not have any reference.

Answer (score 9):

It is Load Constant. It loads an item from the constant pool onto the stack. The available types are:

- `int`
- `float`
- `java.lang.String`
- `java.lang.Class`

The Java 7 JVM added [`java.lang.invoke.MethodType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodType.html) and [`java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html).

The special variant `ldc2_w` will load an item of either `long` or `double` type onto the stack.