# Java Primitives and Wrappers promoted + boxed! What process is doing JVM here

Tags: java, int, wrapper, primitive

I'm trying to go for 1Z0-815. This code I was making:

```
public class PromotedPlusBoxed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       /*AUTOMATIC PROMOTION*/   
       final byte byteValue = 10;
       final short shortValue = 10;        
       final char charValue = 10;
       final int intValue = 10;
       final long longValue = 10;
       final float floatValue = 10;
       final double doubleValue = 10;
       /**/
       final Byte byteWrapperValue = 10;/*WHAT PROCESS IS HERE? A HIDDEN = (byte)10;? a performing a single boxed process.*/
       final Short shortWrapperValue = 10;/*WHAT PROCESS IS HERE? A HIDDEN = (short)10;? a performing a single boxed process.*/        
       final Character charWrapperValue = 10;/*WHAT PROCESS IS HERE? A HIDDEN = (char)10;? a performing a single boxed process.*/        
       final Integer intWrapperValue = 10;
       final Long longWrapperValue = 10;/*CAN'T PERFORM TWO-PHASE PROCESS 1). PROMOTED + 2).BOXED*/
       final Float floatWrapperValue = 10;/*CAN'T PERFORM TWO-PHASE PROCESS 1). PROMOTED + 2).BOXED*/
       final Double doubleWrapperValue = 10;/*CAN'T PERFORM TWO-PHASE PROCESS 1). PROMOTED + 2).BOXED*/
    }    
}
```

I understand the primitives part also, and I understand that I cannot do this.

```
  final Long longWrapperValue = 10;/*CAN'T PERFORM TWO-PHASE PROCESS 1). PROMOTED + 2).BOXED*/
  final Float floatWrapperValue = 10;/*CAN'T PERFORM TWO-PHASE PROCESS 1). PROMOTED + 2).BOXED*/
  final Double doubleWrapperValue = 10;/*CAN'T PERFORM TWO-PHASE PROCESS 1). PROMOTED + 2).BOXED*/
```

Because 10 is a literal int a 2 process needs to made first promoted to float,long and double and later boxed to the respective wrappers.

But this is compiling.

```
 final Byte byteWrapperValue = 10;/*WHAT PROCESS IS HERE? A HIDDEN = (byte)10;? a performing a single boxed process.*/
 final Short shortWrapperValue = 10;/*WHAT PROCESS IS HERE? A HIDDEN = (short)10;? a performing a single boxed process.*/        
 final Character charWrapperValue = 10;/*WHAT PROCESS IS HERE? A HIDDEN = (char)10;? a performing a single boxed process.*/
```

What is the process here? 10 is getting promoted to byte and later boxed into a Byte is that a 2 process right? but is not working for a Long what is the diff between Long and Byte,Character,Short in this process.

In summary: I want to understand why can a literal int can be boxed into a Byte,Character,Short and not into a Long.

Comment: I want to understand why can a literal int can be boxed into a Byte,Character,Short and not into a Long. Tha'ts all.

Comment: Related: [How java auto boxing/unboxing works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648627/how-java-auto-boxing-unboxing-works) and [Why do we use autoboxing and unboxing in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the bytecode. If we want to view it though, we have to make it compile first, so change your last example to this:

```java
final Byte byteWrapperValue = 10;
final Short shortWrapperValue = 10;
final Character charWrapperValue = 10;
final Integer intWrapperValue = 10;
final Long longWrapperValue = 10L;       <-- Added L
final Float floatWrapperValue = 10.0f;   <-- Added .0f
final Double doubleWrapperValue = 10.0d; <-- Added .0d
```

> for the sake of readability I removed the `LINENUMBER` and `ASTORE` instructions)

Then when viewing the bytecode we see this:

```
   L0
    BIPUSH 10
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Byte.valueOf (B)Ljava/lang/Byte;
   L1
    BIPUSH 10
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Short.valueOf (S)Ljava/lang/Short;
   L2
    BIPUSH 10
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Character.valueOf (C)Ljava/lang/Character;
   L3
    BIPUSH 10
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Integer.valueOf (I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   L4
    LDC 10
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Long.valueOf (J)Ljava/lang/Long;
   L5
    LDC 10.0
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Float.valueOf (F)Ljava/lang/Float;
   L6
    LDC 10.0
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Double.valueOf (D)Ljava/lang/Double;
```

Note that for every `10` up until `Integer` we use the `BIPUSH` instruction (you can see all at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)) which means that it pushes a *byte* as an *integer* onto the stack.

Whereas with `10L`, `10.0f` and `10.0d` we use the `LDC` instruction, which is similar but not exactly, it is used to load a *constant* from the constant pool, it may be static or dynamic.

(**The later may be the cause that it doesn't compile in the first place.**)

You also see that the compiler autoboxes the values pushed onto the stack with the corresponding Wrapper-class method. (e.g. `Byte.valueOf()`)

Also when analyzing a simple example:

```java
long l = 10;
Long l2 = l;
```

You can see the same, this time it just makes it in two steps:

```
   L0
    LDC 10 # load the value from the constant pool
   L1
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Long.valueOf (J)Ljava/lang/Long; # convert the value to the wrapper type with autoboxing
```

More reading:

- [How java auto boxing/unboxing works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648627/how-java-auto-boxing-unboxing-works)
- [Why do we use autoboxing and unboxing in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java)
- [How does bipush work in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167675/how-does-bipush-work-in-jvm)
- [I'm curious about what ldc short for in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264012/im-curious-about-what-ldc-short-for-in-jvm)